# Can you add the same rendering to multiple SXA Cache Settings items

Tags: sxa, presentation, caching

Is it supported to add the same rendering to two (or more) different cache settings items?

Currently, there is no warning if you do so, but I'm unsure if this is a valid thing to do or not?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can answer this question on your own by using DotPeek. The `GetSiteLevelCaching` processor in `GetRenderingCaching` pipeline is responsible for processing those items. The code looks like this:

```
public void Process(GetRenderingCachingArgs args)
{
    ...

    var renderingId = args.Rendering.RenderingItem?.ID.ToString() ?? args.Rendering.RenderingItemPath;
    foreach (Item cacheSetting in cachingFolder.Children)
    {
        ...

        if (!cacheSetting[Templates.CacheSettings.Fields.Renderings].Contains(renderingId))
        {
            continue;
        }

        PopulateCacheOptions(args.Rendering, cacheSetting);
        args.Rendering[Constants.InheritedCaching] = "1";

        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is a `break` statement in the main loop. That means that when there is a CacheSetting item which will contain current rendering, we will read caching settings and break the loop. In other words - only the first CacheSetting item containing particular rendering will be processed.